# Can't authorise settings change or install new apps

Tags: macos, password, administrator

## 1

Hello,

I have a problem authorising any admin tasks on Yosemite 10.10.5 (like installing new apps, unlocking system settings etc.). I have an admin account with a password, yet the system won't authorise it. The prompt just shakes around as if the password was incorrect. However, I'm able to log into my account without problems, so I assume the login details are fine.

I've noticed that the "Username" field is blank by default (while usualy it's already there when the prompt appears) - please see the attached image file. Even if I type the username manually, it still wouldn't work.

[image: prompt]

Not sure what to do about it, I've never seen anything like this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **Macintosh HD->Users** and see what your username folder is, and use that when prompted.

Sometimes the username and name you see aren't always the same. As an example, I have profiles named **Christian (Work)** and **Christian (Personal)**. The actual usernames are **christian** and **christianpersona**l, respectively. When prompted for an admin, I have to use **christian** to gain access. This is because I have changed the profile name after it was first created, giving it a different viewing name than the user folder.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. I've done as you've suggested and it's still not working. The folder name is "macos" and the prompt wouldn't accept it (and is acting as if the password was incorrect). I'm typing the correct password that works perfectly well with the logon screen.

Comment: Can you run `dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'` in the terminal? This should list the actual usernames on your Mac, which you can use if they are an admin. Also, if you have set a root password you should be able to type root as the username.